# Windows 10 background processes - how are they starting?

Tags: windows, process, windows-10

Task Manager is telling me I have utterly useless processes running in the background, like Candy Crush Saga (which I don't play), and NVIDIA Streamer Service (I don't own an NVIDIA graphics card any more).

But in the the Start-up tab, there are only a few items and they're not related to these processes. I checked in msconfig, but the Startup tab of that no longer seems to exist, just a message directing me to the Start-up tab of Task Manager.

How are these tasks starting, and how can I disable them?

Comment: Use [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to see the thread

Answer (score 2):

For non-Metro apps in general, use [Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx). If you don't want to just uninstall the service, disable it from `Service` snap in `Computer Management`. If you don't want to just uninstall the Metro app (literally just right click and uninstall it), remove its `Lock Screen` permission either from Control Panel's centralized permission list or the app configuration pane.